# Facebook SDK 3.1 iOS: How to check whether Facebook is accessible?

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, ping

I'm writing my first iOS app with Facebook integration and am trying to handle some of the edge cases elegantly.  Right now I'm considering the case of no internet access, or specifically no Facebook access.

The "Scrumptious" tutorial handles this rather poorly in my opinion.  When presented with the Login screen w/o internet access, the user has the option to click the Login button which then abandons them at an inaccessible page in Safari.  I'd prefer to alert the user with a message explaining the problem.

So my question is, what's the best way to "ping" the Facebook service w/o anyone yet logged in to best ensure that a subsequent login request will be successful?

Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated to facebook apple provides the reachability example, it checks for network availability, i am using it as a pre-check before even trying to connect

Comment: Oh cool, this may be exactly what I need.  I would prefer a Facebook SDK solution if there is one, but if not this sounds like a good alternative.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try find in example a

```
-(void) sessionStateChanged: (FBSession*) session
                      state: (FBSessionState) state
                      error: (NSError*) error
{
   switch(state)
  {
    case FBSessionStateOpen:
    {
       // Logged
     break;
    }

    case FBSessionStateClosed:
    {
       // Logouted
     break;
    }

    case FBSessionStateFailed:
    {
       // connect failed or some error
       // it seems, this place what you need ?
     break;
    }
  }
}
```

**UPD**

Or you can check a Safari error at here (FBRequestConnection.m)

```
-(void) completeWithResponse: (NSURLResponse*) response
                        data: (NSData*) data
                     orError: (NSError*) error
{
     //Try check this params at each your case
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply @CReaTuS.  However the problem here is that sessionStateChanged will never get called in the case of an initial login because the process will get stuck in Safari (though I think your suggestion will work for the case where the user already has a token and no redirect outside of the app is required).

Comment: Cool I'll try out your new suggestion when I have a chance!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Harald you can use the Reachability sample from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Just import the Reachability.h and Reachability.m into your project.

If you just want to do a one time check on if you are connected to the internet then consider this.

```
+(BOOL)isConnectionToInternet
{
    Reachability* internetReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [internetReachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (netStatus) {
        case NotReachable:NSLog(@"NotReachable");
            return NO;
        case ReachableViaWiFi:NSLog(@"ReachableViaWiFi");
            return YES;
        case ReachableViaWWAN:NSLog(@"ReachableViaWWAN");
            return YES;
    }
}
```

You can also check for a specific url such as facebook.com using the reachabilityWithAddress method in Reachability.

Hope this helps.